# AddThis - turning it on and off

Tags: javascript, addthis

I've hit a problem I can seem to find a way around.

Essentially, I have a button with the "addthis_button" class, hovering over the button displays the AddThis box. Works perfectly :)

However I need to turn this on and off based on the users other actions around the page, is it possible to turn the AddThis hover event on and off as and when I need to?

For example, I have a button that says "Share" at the top of my page. Rolling over it displays AddThis. I then go and click a few things on the page. The share button has greyed out nicely but when I roll over it I still get AddThis.

I've tried re initializing AddThis completely but to no avail.

Thank you for any help you can give.

Edit: jsFiddle link hjsfiddle.net/49Pgf/

Comment: please post some code?

Comment: Hi iBlue, thank you for your reply but the code I'm using at the moment isn't the problem. I'm asking if turning AddThis on and off is possible.

Comment: It's definitely possible, anything that's been set up to happen in javascript can also be set to not happen with javascript. Unfortunately no one is going to be able to show you how to turn it off until they can see how you've turned it on in the first place.

Comment: Hi Racheet, apologies if I wasn't clear. I'm using the "AddThis" plugin. To initialize it all I do is include the script file and add a class of "addthis_button" to the button. The library takes over and does the rest.

Comment: I've created a jsFiddle that shows exactly what I'm doing without any surrounding code noise. http://jsfiddle.net/49Pgf/

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work to disable AddThis from showing the menu on hover:

```
addthis.button('.addthis_button', {ui_click:true}, {});
```

This requires an actual click on your link to show the menu.  And then of course, you can re-enable it by calling the opposite:

```
addthis.button('.addthis_button', {ui_click:false}, {});
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thank you for your help Sol, apologies for the delay in getting back to you (been away). Unfortunately this didn't work. The click event isn't removed. See: http://jsfiddle.net/49Pgf/2/